# Can we say: "I picked up that xxx"?

Tags: grammar, clauses, that

Would the following sentence still be grammatical if "information" is omitted?

> "I picked up <strike>information</strike> that oranges are bad for you."

It's clear that what I've picked up is information regarding oranges.

Comment: It’s not idiomatic; not something a native soeaker would say. It would not be easily understood, although someone might figure it out.

Comment: I think the meaning would be obvious in context (it couldn't really mean anything else), but agree it's non-standard to follow "pick up" with a that-clause and no noun. It's hard to search for because expressions like "pick up that litter" are valid English, but I can't see any examples in the OED or M-W.

Comment: It's odd but grammatical. The reason it feels odd is that it's hard to think of a context where it would be natural -- that's essentially what "grammatical" means. But if someone is eavesdropping and reporting on what they heard, that sentence might come out naturally, imo.